# Procedure or function 'x' expects parameter '@y', which was not supplied.Got error on c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldataadapter

First at all, i know questions like these are duplicate BUT, please pay attention to this expect one.
Here is my C# code behind which raise the error as :

> Procedure or function 'aaa' expects parameter '@bbb', which was not supplied.

```
if (Dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Cmd = new SqlCommand();
    Cmd.CommandText = ("[dbo].[aaa]");
    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@bbb", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@LettType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = LetterType;
    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@IsTajamo", SqlDbType.Char, 1).Value = 1;
    Da = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd.CommandText, Con);
    Dt.Clear();
    /*Line72:*/    
    Da.Fill(Dt);
}
```

Technically, I can't found where is the error. I passed all parameters. And when i execute my stored procedure separately in MS-SQL It work right with these values.

Can you experts please help me on this issue?
Attention : here is Stored Proc :

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[aaa] (@bbb Int , @LettType CHAR(3) , @IsTajamo CHAR(1))

AS
BEGIN

select 1


END
```

Attention : (may be this can help, here is my stack-trace) :

> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
>   isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry,
>   SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet
>   dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords,
>   String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior
>   behavior) at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable
>   dataTable) at WebService.Services.GetLettersList(String UserName,
>   String PassPhrase, String CodeName, String LetterType) in
>   D:\Amiri\WebService\WebService\Services.asmx.cs:line 79

Comment: @Satpal There is no problem with Procedure.
if you just read the question properly before flagging. you can understand i said. procedure is working properly.

Comment: I have read the question and not flagged yet. However to me problem seems procedure  snippet will be helpful for resolution

Comment: @نرخیاب: arguing with those trying to help you is a good way to make that help go away.  That said, the most common reason for this error in my experience is misspelling the parameter name.  Check your spelling.

Comment: We need to see how you are executing the stored procedure to try to understand where the problem is.

Comment: @alex I bring The procedure back

Comment: @SamAxe Check the question again please. i edit the code

Comment: Salam. Probably Stored prodecuer does not have parameter @bbb. Please write your SP signature .

Comment: @alex Manually right click on the SP and execute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your line:

```
Da = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd.CommandText, Con);
```

you are only passing the *name* of the procedure and ignoring the parameters. Pass only `Cmd` (and add that connection to the command) to use your defined params.

Comment: if (Dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {

                            Da = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd.CommandText, Con);
                            Da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@bbb", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
                            Da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@LettType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = LetterType;
                            Da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@IsTajamo", SqlDbType.Char, 1).Value = 1;

WRONG ANSWER
           WRONG ANSWER

Comment: Also, the `@LettType` parameter is declared as `char(3)` but the in the .net code it's declared as `varchar`.

Answer (score 2):

@Hans Kesting is correct, but I don't think it is explained well. What is happening with this...

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd.CommandText, Con);
```

...is you are implicitly creating a new `SqlCommand` that has the same `CommandText` as `Cmd`. It is the same as if you just literally used `[dbo].[aaa]` as the argument value. Therefore, this new `SqlCommand` has no `SqlParameters` assigned. You could then do: `SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(....`, but that is a mess.

What you need to do is use the `SqlCommand` (`Cmd`) itself. But you must also make sure it is tied to the connection:

```
   Cmd = Con.CreateCommand(); //This hooks up the connection to this command
   Cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[aaa]";
   Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   Cmd.Parameters.Add("@bbb", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
   Cmd.Parameters.Add("@LettType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = LetterType;
   Cmd.Parameters.Add("@IsTajamo", SqlDbType.Char, 1).Value = 1;
   Da = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd); //Just the command
   Dt.Clear();
   Da.Fill(Dt);
```